# adding UILongPressGestureRecognizer to last tableview cell fails to detect locationInView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8.1

I'm trying to add a UILongPressGestureRecongnizer to each tableview cell. The following code works in all cases except the last cell:

**ViewDidLoad**:

```
let longpress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")
longpress.minimumPressDuration = 0.35
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longpress)
```

**handleLongPress:**

```
func handleLongPress(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer!) {
    let localLongPress = sender as UILongPressGestureRecognizer
    var locationInView = localLongPress.locationInView(tableView)

    // returns nil in the case of last cell
    // but strangely only on Ended State
    var indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView)
    if indexPath != nil {
        var cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as MyCellTableViewCell
        println("Long press Block .................");     
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
            println("Long press Ended");
        } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
            println("Long press detected."); 
        }
    } 
}
```

In the case of my last cell, I always see the `UIGestureRecognizerState.Began` but I do not see the `UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended`. I see both states for every cell, except the last tableviewcell. `tableview.indexPathForRowAtPoint()` resolves to nil in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "capture"

Comment: I couldn't think of a good title, basically in my logs I always see "Long Press detected", but in the case of my last tableViewCell, I do not see "Long Press Ended"

Comment: Ok, reading the question further, the actual problem is that `indexPathForRowAtPoint` is returning nil when you should be seeing the Ended?  If that's the case, you won't see the message.  If that's actually the case, then you should clarify the question (and title) to reflect the real problem.

Comment: It is impossible to reproduce.

Comment: The only time I see any issues is if you touch and hold on the last cell and drag down to non-existent cells.  If you're still seeing the issue, it's likely that it's caused by code your not showing here.

Comment: Yes it was. It was caused by this: self.view.addSubview(player.view) replacing it with this: self.tableView.addSubview(player.view) fixed the issue. Thanks for looking into this guys